# Windows Batch File launched by ShellExecuteA() ignores the specified working directory

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I called `ShellExecuteExA()` in order to run a batch file.

I use `SHELLEXECUTEINFOA` and specify a *working directory*

However, when the batch file runs it doesn't start in the *specified working directory* and the programs run from the batch file don't use the *specified working directory* when they run.

```cpp
bool shellExecute(const fs::path& p, const int show, const std::string_view parameters={},
                      const fs::path& working_dir={}, const std::string verb="open");
bool shellExecute(const std::string& path, const int show, const std::string_view parameters="",
                      const fs::path& working_dir={}, const std::string verb="open");
```

```cpp
    /**
     * Opens a path using ShellExecute
     * @param p the fs::path to open
     * \param show any show value from ShowWindow()
     *        - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
     * \param working_dir the working directory to use or {} for none
     * \param verb the verb to use
     *             (e.g. NULL, "open", "explore", "find", "edit", "print", "properties", "runas", etc.)
     * @return true if the file was launched successfully, false otherwise.
     */
    bool shellExecute(const fs::path& p, const int show, const std::string_view parameters,
                      const fs::path& working_dir, const std::string verb) {
        return shellExecute(p.generic_string(), show, parameters, working_dir);
    }
```

```cpp
    /**
     * Launches an executable file using ShellExecute.
     * \param path The full path to the executable file.
     * \param show any show value from ShowWindow()
     *        - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
     * \param parameters the parameters to pass to the program being launched
     * \param working_dir the working directory to use or {} for none
     * \param verb the verb to use
     *             (e.g. NULL, "open", "explore", "find", "edit", "print", "properties", "runas", etc.)
     * \return true if the file was launched successfully, false otherwise.
     */
    bool shellExecute(const std::string& path, const int show, const std::string_view parameters,
                      const fs::path& working_dir, const std::string verb) {

        SHELLEXECUTEINFOA execInfo = { sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOA) };
        execInfo.lpVerb = verb.c_str();
        execInfo.lpFile = path.c_str();
        execInfo.lpParameters = parameters.data();
        execInfo.nShow = show;
        execInfo.lpDirectory = working_dir.empty() ? NULL : working_dir.string().c_str();

        return ShellExecuteExA(&execInfo) == TRUE;
    }
```

### calling code

```cpp
const path& bat = // full (non-relative) path was set to batch file ;
const path& bat_folder = // full (non-relative) path was set to folder of batch file ;

shellExecute(bat, SW_NORMAL, {}, bat_folder );
```

How can I fix this?

characters used in my path objects are just regular english ASCII characters and file system punctuation

I have tried `working_dir.generic_string()`, `working_dir.make_preferred()` as well

I am on Windows 11

p.s. setting the working directory I'm pretty sure works with running executables, at least I seem to remember it working, but running this batch file is a problem

### Windows Terminal display is:

`(Visual Studio Project Folder Path)>batch file commands`

not

`(bat_folder contents)>batch file commands`

if I pass `bat_folder` as a parameter to the batch file and `cd %1`, then I can get the batch files commands to run correctly and locate the files they reference, because it is in the correct directory for all the relative paths to make sense in the batch file. But I would prefer not to use this workaround. I would prefer for the batch file to start in the working directory specified to `ShellExecuteExA()`

Comment: show your code please

Comment: ShellExecuteA doesnt take that structure, ShellExecuteExA does tho

Comment: @pm100 sorry, typo

Comment: `working_dir.string()` returns a temporary `std::string`. The pointer returned by `working_dir.string().c_str()`, that you put into `execInfo.lpDirectory`, becomes dangling at the next semicolon when that temporary is destroyed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks that solved it. I tried storing it before but didn't do that correctly, now I did it correctly and it works

Comment: comments answer by igor works